# Get the previous element of an index from a Point list

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Point list that stores (x, y) values. The list is this

```
List<Point> path = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, I want to be able to get the previous index of a specific index from that list. For example I have this Point list :

```
[(4,4), (1,4), (2,3), (0,1)]
```

How can I get the previous index of (2,3), that would the (1,4),(4,4)?
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "*previous index*"?

Comment: of (2,3) the previous would be (1,4).

Comment: What about `(4,4)` then?

Comment: ok sure why not :)

Comment: For that list that you have, `path.get(0)` would get you `(4,4)` and `path.get(1)` would get you `(1,4)`. So if you know what index your current point is, then that `index-1` would get you the previous one. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes pretty much. How do I implement this? by using a for loop or something else?

Comment: @Wannahelp have you resolved this issue? If any of the answers solved your problem remember to [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `equals(Object obj)` method so that we can perform search.

```
class Point {

  public int x, y;
  
  public Point(int x, int y){ this.x=x; this.y=y;}
        
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o instanceof Point){
      Point p = (Point) o;
      return x == p.x && y == p.y;
    }
    return false;
  }
        
  public String toString(){
    return String.format("(%d,%d)", x,y);
  }
}
```

`indexOf()` will return the index where p is found.  Or you could use `List.indexOf()` instead.

```
static int indexOf(List<Point> path, Point p){
  for(int i=0; i<path.size(); i++)
    if (path.get(i).equals(p)) return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Find the index of the point
Every point before that point are previous points.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
  List<Point> path = new ArrayList<>(
                List.of(new Point(0,0), new Point(1,1), 
                        new Point(2,2), new Point(3,3)));
        
  int index = indexOf(path, new Point(2,2));
        
  List<Point> prevs = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
    prevs.add(path.get(i));
        
  System.out.println(prevs);
}
```

Output:

```
[(0,0), (1,1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```java
 // Define the point or get the point that you are searching for some different way
Point x = Point(2,3)
int previousIndex = path.indexOf(x) - 1;

// Make sure we are not out of bounds
if (previousIndex >= 0){
   return path.get(previousIndex)
   // Would return (1, 4)
}
```

Make use of `indexOf` and make sure you are not out of bounds. That is pretty much all there is to it. If you want to get all previous points you could do something like this

```java
new ArrayList(paths.subList(0 ,previousIndex+1))
```